# Quisiera ordenar un array que cree a partir de mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, array

Saludos amigos,quisiera saber como ordenar una lista que cree a partir de un `mysqli_fetch_array`.

Aparte de este código tengo un buscador, lo que quiero es, que los resultados de la búsqueda me aparezcan ordenados en alguna fila especifica, por ejemplo numero del código o nombre.

```
<?php
require ("datos_de_acceso.php");
$conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Fallo al conectar con la BBDD";
    exit();
}

mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf-8");
mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die ("No se encuentra la base de datos");
mysqli_query($conexion, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$busqueda=$_GET["buscar"];

if (is_numeric($busqueda)){
 $consulta="SELECT * FROM hoja1 WHERE codigo LIKE '%$busqueda%'";
 $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
}else{
 $consulta="SELECT * FROM hoja1 WHERE materia LIKE '%$busqueda%'";
 $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
}

while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
 echo "<table border='1px' width='51%' align='left'><tr>";
 echo "<td width='4%'>" . $fila['numero'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td width='8%'>" . $fila['codigo'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td width='30%'>" . $fila['materia'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td width='8%'>" . $fila['seccion'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr></table>";  
}
?>
```

Comment: El código que estás usando tiene vulnerabilidades que deberías corregir. Por favor lee [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18233/127)

Answer (score 3):

Tienes dos opciones, o incluso combinarlas:

1. Usar `ORDER BY` al momento de hacer la consulta, para ordenarlos resultados por el campo o los campos que desees, en forma ascendente o descendente:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM hoja1 WHERE codigo LIKE '%$busqueda%' ORDER BY codigo ASC
   ```

   Ordenar por más de un campo (primero por nombre descendente y luego por código):

   ```
   SELECT * FROM hoja1 WHERE codigo LIKE '%$busqueda%' ORDER BY nombre DESC, codigo ASC
   ```
2. Usar una biblioteca de Javascript (para no reinventar la rueda) en el frontend para ordenar la tabla en cualquier momento por el campo que desees, aunque dependiendo de la cantidad de registros puede no ser tan interesante esta solución (en términos de rendimiento):

   Tablesort: https://github.com/tristen/tablesort

   Datatables (requiere jQuery): https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

Acá te dejo una función para ordenar un array en base a 1 campo.

```
private function orderMultiDimensionalArray($toOrderArray, $field, $inverse) {

    $position = array();
    $newRow = array();

    foreach ($toOrderArray as $key => $row) {
        $position[$key] = $row[$field];
        $newRow[$key] = $row;
    }

    if ($inverse) {
       arsort($position);
    } else {
        asort($position);
    }

    $returnArray = array();

     foreach ($position as $key => $pos) {
         $returnArray[] = $newRow[$key];
     }

    return $returnArray;
 }
```

Los parámetros son:

1. $toOrderArray = Es el array con los datos a ordenar.
2. $field = Es el campo por el que queres ordenar. Por ej: numero o codigo de tu array.
3. $inverse = TRUE ordena de forma ascendente.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tengo una consulta quisiera ordenar por fecha mi tabla pero me da error esta sintaxis:
  $sql = "SELECT*FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$Usuario' AND ORDER BY folio ASC";

Comment: Esto parece más bien una pregunta pero está en el sitio de las respuestas. Borra la respuesta e inicia una nueva pregunta, de otra forma no te contestará nadie.